# How to access time in jfree.data

Tags: jfreechart, imagej

I am trying to access time from jfree.data and adding it to my results table in ImageJ. But this does not work and I don't know why. Here is my code:

```
// Set IJ settings
ResultsTable rt = new ResultsTable();


// create a series that automatically discard data > 30 seconds old... 
TimeSeries intensities = new TimeSeries("Int"); 
intensities.setMaximumItemAge(30000); 
TimeSeriesCollection dataset = new TimeSeriesCollection(); 
dataset.addSeries(intensities); 
ImageProcessor ip;

//Run while Live
while (true) {
    mm.live().snap(true);
    ip = mm.live().getDisplay().getImagePlus().getProcessor();
    ImageStatistics stats = ip.getStatistics(); 
    intensities.add(new Millisecond(), stats.mean);
    img = images.get(0);
    rt.incrementCounter();
    rt.addValue("Time",intensities.millisecond);
    rt.addValue("Mean",stats.mean);
    rt.show("Results");
    Thread.sleep(10);   
}
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: It would help if you could narrow down the problem to an ImageJ problem because here we deal with *ImageJ*, not jFree.

Comment: Cheers Herbie, I'm open to any and all suggestions on how to get time and add it to the results table. I just thought that since jFree already contained the X variable I need, and I am using it for something else, it would be possible to access it and output it to the results table.

Comment: So your are saying that the problem is with ImageJ-coding of general table entries?

Comment: A [tag:jfreechart] `TimeSeries` holds a `List` of `TimeSeriesDataItem`, for [example](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A230513+%5Bjfreechart%5D+TimeSeries+TimeSeriesDataItem), each having a `RegularTimePeriod` from which you can get a `Date`. I suspect that the problem is sleeping on the EDT; see [*Concurrency in Swing*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) and [*How to Use Swing Timers*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html).

Comment: I actually suspect the problem is that I don't know how to format java correctly and that you can't actually write "intensities.millisecond" and expect to get milliseconds. I will take a look at swingtimers, but I suspect that if I can figure those out, I can also figure out metadata or coords or jfree.data

Comment: long t=System.currentTimeMillis(); followed by your processing code and then t=System.currentTimeMillis()-t; gives the processing time. However this has nothing to do with ImageJ and ImageJ-Results tables. Be aware of the possibility that longs may not be suited as Results table entries.

Comment: The first example I cited shows how to get milliseconds, which you can also get from a `Date`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some ImageJ-Java code I use for data entry to an ImageJ-Results table:

```
ResultsTable table = ResultsTable.getResultsTable( "myTable" );
if ( table == null )
     table = new ResultsTable();
else
     table.incrementCounter();
table.addValue( "Data", value );
table.show( "myTable" );
```

Comment: Hi Herbie. Thanks for the code. I am able to add entries to the ResultsTable. What I am trying to do is to measure a live image from MicroManager and adding the time to each measurement. My code works, except I don't know how to access time. Preferably time since the start of acquisition, but I will take any time I can get at this point. I can see that time exists in jFree, in coords and in metadata, but I just don't know enough code to access any of those in a usable way.

Comment: That's why I was asking above but you didn't make it clear. Initially you wrote: "[…] adding it to my results table in ImageJ. But this does not work […]"

Comment: Yes, and "it" referring to the time. But I see how I could have been clearer.

Comment: Can't help you with MicroManager and jFree… Maybe the variable type of "time" isn't suited for table entry. Did you ever access this variable and inspect it via System.out?